# sistema de questionario com php

Tags: php

Tenho duvidas fiz um sisitema de questionario com php mas o resulta do só dá Resposta errada e não Resposta certa

abaixo os códigos:

**HTML**

```
<form action="questionario_analise.php" method="post" name="questionaro">
    (1) A estancia Montana é um:<br />
    (a) Salão de Eventos
    <input name="questao1" type="radio" value="a" /><br />
    (b) Quadra de Esportes
    <input name="questao1" type="radio" value="b" /><br />
    (c) Cinema
    <input name="questao1" type="radio" value="c" /><br /><br />

    (2) A estancia Montana suporta:<br />
    (a) 400 pessoas
    <input name="questao2" type="radio" value="a" /><br /> 
    (b) 1000 pessoas
    <input name="questao2" type="radio" value="b" /><br /> 
    (c) 500 pessoas
    <input name="questao2" type="radio" value="c" /><br /><br />

    (3) Campo Grande é :<br />
    (a) Capital
    <input name="questao3" type="radio" value="a" /><br /> 
    (b) Interior
    <input name="questao3" type="radio" value="b" /><br /> 
    (c) Rural
    <input name="questao3" type="radio" value="c" /><br /><br />

    <input name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$questao1=$_POST['questao1']."<br>";
$questao2=$_POST['questao2']."<br>";
$questao3=$_POST['questao3']."<br>";

echo "Questao 1 = ".$questao1."<br>";
echo "Questao 2 = ".$questao2."<br>";
echo "Questao 3 = ".$questao3."<br>";

$resposta1 = "a";
$resposta2 = "b";
$resposta3 = "c";

$acertou=0;
$errou=0;

if ($questao1 == $resposta1)
    echo "Resposta correta<br>";
else
    echo"Resposta errada<br>";

if ($questao2 == $resposta3)
    echo "Resposta correta<br>";
else
    echo"Resposta errada<br>"; 

if($questao3 == $resposta1)
    echo "Resposta correta<br>";
else
    echo"Resposta errada<br>"; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Teste o php da seguinte forma, removendo os 
 do POST:

```
  <?php
        $questao1 = $_POST['questao1']; // Sem o <br> aqui
        $questao2 = $_POST['questao2']; // Sem o <br> aqui
        $questao3 = $_POST['questao3']; // Sem o <br> aqui

        echo "Questao 1 = ".$questao1."<br>";
        echo "Questao 2 = ".$questao2."<br>";
        echo "Questao 3 = ".$questao3."<br>";

        $resposta1 = "a";
        $resposta2 = "b";
        $resposta3 = "c";

        $acertou=0;
        $errou=0;

        if ($questao1 == $resposta1){
            echo "Resposta correta<br>";
        }else{
            echo"Resposta errada<br>";

        if ($questao2 == $resposta3){
            echo "Resposta correta<br>";
          }else{
            echo"Resposta errada<br>"; 

        if($questao3 == $resposta1){
            echo "Resposta correta<br>";
       }else{
            echo"Resposta errada<br>"; 

        ?>
```

Implementei seu código php colocando as `{` nas condições  e também removi os `<br>` dos   `$questao1 = $_POST['questao1'];` pois como você esta guardando o resultado em uma variável não é indicado passar `html` junto uma vez que ele não é um parâmetro.

Answer (score 1):

Remova os `<br>` concatenados indevidamente nos POSTs, senão a comparação não funciona.

```
$questao1 = $_POST['questao1']."<br>"; // errado
$questao1 = $_POST['questao1'];        // certo
```

Aplicando ao código:

```
$questao1 = $_POST['questao1']; 
$questao2 = $_POST['questao2'];
$questao3 = $_POST['questao3'];

$resposta1 = "a";
$resposta2 = "b";
$resposta3 = "c";

$acertou=0;
$errou=0;

if ($questao1 == $resposta1)
    echo "Resposta correta<br>";
else
    echo"Resposta errada<br>";

if ($questao2 == $resposta3)
    echo "Resposta correta<br>";
else
    echo"Resposta errada<br>"; 

if($questao3 == $resposta1)
    echo "Resposta correta<br>";
else
    echo"Resposta errada<br>";
```